# Decoding HTML twice in rails

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby, decode

I'm pulling data from a XML file which comes out as doubly encoded HTML which I am able to decode into straight HTML using `raw`, `h`, or `String.html_safe`. Doubling up any of these methods doesn't seem to decode further so when I print the string in the view, it renders as encoded HTML.

For example, I might get the string:

```
@paragraph = &amp;lt;p&amp;gt;This is a Paragraph.&amp;lt;/p&amp;gt;
```

When I print `<%= @paragraph %>` I get `&lt;p&gt;This is a Paragraph.&lt;/p&gt;` showing in my browser. Printing `<%= raw @paragraph %>` renders `<p>This is a Paragraph.</p>`.

So far as expected. But now when I try to decode again: `<%= raw (raw @paragraph) %>` I get `<p>This is a Paragraph.</p>`. No matter how many times I call `raw` or any of the other two methods, I continue to get encoded HTML.

What I'm looking for is of course:

This is a paragraph.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use CGI.escapeHTML/CGI.unescapeHTML

```
 irb(main):043:0> CGI.escapeHTML "<p>This is a Paragraph.</p>"
 => "&lt;p&gt;This is a Paragraph.&lt;/p&gt;"

 irb(main):090:0> CGI.unescapeHTML "&lt;p&gt;This is a Paragraph.&lt;/p&gt;"
 => "<p>This is a Paragraph.</p>"
```

You may also want to have a look at http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/SanitizeHelper.html#method-i-strip_tags to remove html tags

Comment: Ha, I'm assuming that's supposed to be `CGI.unescapeHTML`. That did the trick though, so thanks!

Comment: "<p>This is a Paragraph.</p>" is unescaped. calling CGI.unescapeHTML will not do anything